# Django 1.9.9 unable to connect Azure SQL database from windows

Tags: python, sql, django, azure, pyodbc

On my `windows` machine, I have following packages installed in my app.

`django: 1.9.9`

`pyodbc==4.0.3`

`django-pyodbc-azure==1.10.4.0`

In my settings.py file..

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
         'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
         'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USERNAME'),
         'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
         'HOST': 'tcp:sdohsandbox.database.windows.net',
         'PORT': '1433',
         'OPTIONS': {
             'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
             'MARS_Connection': 'True',
         },
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 120,
     }
}
```

When I start server I am getting following error..

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Django 1.9.9 is not supported.`

Though I have latest version of `pyodbc` I am getting error.

Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed a version of `django-pyodbc-azure` that does not support Django 1.10. The [project page on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pyodbc-azure) says:

> If you want to use it on older versions of Django, specify an appropriate version number (1.9.x.x for Django 1.9) at installation like this:
>
> ```
> pip install "django-pyodbc-azure<1.10"
> ```

Comment: I did that. Now I have `django 1.9.12` and `django-pyodbc-azure==1.9.12.0` Now  I am getting error `Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

Comment: I have provided dbname, user, password in string

Comment: That sounds like a different issue, I can't help you with that.

Comment: @Shri you should mark this as answer and start another question

Comment: Yes. Thanks @Alasdair I also resolved another issue.. I just installed `ODBC Driver 13` into system and it worked.